# How to choose a non busy CUDA device?

Tags: cuda, cluster-computing, gpgpu, gpu, hpc

I'm working on a cluster with a lot of nodes, and each node has two gpus. In the cluster, I can't launch "nvidia-smi" to check which device is busy. My code selects the best device (with cudaChooseDevice) in terms of capability, but when the cluster assign me the same node for two different jobs, then I have two tasks running on the same gpu.

My question is: There is a way to check at runtime if the device is busy or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cluster managers should install and use cluster management (job-scheduling) software that allows them to assign and track GPUs just like CPUs and memory.  There are a number of job schedulers that can do this.  Even without explicit GPU support in the job-scheduler, it's possible to build job entry/exit scripts that will assign GPUs properly.

You can effectively include the same functionality that `nvidia-smi` uses by embedding [NVML](https://developer.nvidia.com/tesla-deployment-kit) in your applications.  Any query or data item reported on by nvidia-smi can be accessed programmatically through NVML.

It's also not clear to me why you could not launch a script for your job which checks which devices are busy using `nvidia-smi`, then picks an un-busy device.

But keep in mind that any runtime check you might do would be subject to the behavior of other applications.  If those applications (whether launched by you or other users) have unusual behavior, your runtime check can easily be defeated.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will see NVML. The cluster uses Slurm, and only checks if there are free resources, but I have not the GPU ID information from Slurm before to launch my task...

Comment: SLURM can manage GPUs via the [generic resource](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/gres.html) mechanism.  Here are some [step-by-step instructions](http://www.hpc-ch.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/CSCS_Schedule_GRES_with_SLURM.pdf) for your cluster managers.  If this is set up correctly, there is no need to inspect the GPU situation from within your job, since only the GPUs you ask for will be assigned, and you will not even be able to access other GPUs on the node.